# Sending mails throught Mandrill with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, mandrill

I've installed WP Mail SMTP plugin on my website and filled in all the credentials from Mandrill. But the mails aren't sent.

When I check in the API log, I get this:

```
{
"raw_message": "Received: from axces-staging.houston-1.hybridmedia.be (unknown [35.157.140.202])\n\t(Authenticated sender: MUum57CGpPUpNlki0O7Bxg@axces.be)\n\tby relay-5.eu-west-1.relay-prod (Postfix) with ESMTPA id 2C5E926E55\n\tfor <dennis@hybridagency.be>; Wed, 21 Nov 2018 09:53:00 +0000 (UTC)\nDate: Wed, 21 Nov 2018 09:52:59 +0000\nTo: dennis@hybridagency.be\nFrom: Axces <info@axces.be>\nSubject: WP Mail SMTP: Test email to dennis@hybridagency.be\nMessage-ID: <e6cd9b1f17f5015000ce9887d17deee2@axces-staging.houston-1.hybridmedia.be>\nX-Mailer: WPMailSMTP/Mailer/smtp 1.3.3\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n\nThis email was sent by Other SMTP mailer, and generated by the WP Mail SMTP WordPress plugin.\n",
"key": "my-api-key-here",
"from_email": null,
"to": [
    "dennis@hybridagency.be"
],
"return_path_domain": null,
"send_at": null,
"from_name": null,
"ip_pool": null,
"async": false
}
```

**My SMTP setting are:**
smtp.mandrillapp.com
Encryption: TLS
Port: 587
Authentication: On
Username: the username given in Mandrill
Password: the API key

What could be wrong? I see "from_name": null in the API log, but there is a from_name in my settings.

[image: SMTP settings]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can to try install [Easy WP SMTP Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/) and insert the smtp details. You can get the solution.

Comment: When I use the plugin, I get this error:
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server:  (0)SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

But very strange, because the connection credentials are correct.

Comment: Do you have try to send the mail without credentials. because there is given the option for testing. so, you can use and try it. you can understand where is the problem.

Comment: No, that doesn't work.
Could it be that this is a free Mandrill account? 
But it says that I can send maximum 25 mails.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem. Testmail was send successfully, but no Email was send, even not in the mandrill->outbound.

Then i found under **settings->api_logs** why my mails not sendet.

In my case i had to add send-raw under options of the API-Key (settings->smtp & API info)